# PUT and DELETE type is throwing error with Serverless framework for lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, serverless, aws-serverless

This is the endpoint details.
Http is PUT.

[image]

1. Tried with allow credentials true, did not work.
2. Updated Cloud front
   permissions to include PUT and delete, did not work.
3. Just having cors: true also did not work.
4. We are setting the origin back with response header but still after the
   preflight the origin is set to *. Because of which we are receiving cors error.
   (Not sure how it is being converted to * because all other endpoints/functions(GET/POST) has proper header origin set.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message is telling you the truth. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: Yes, but the problem is we are setting the header with proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin. It is working with POST and type but when we change it to PUT/DELETE, we are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

We are using version 2.72.0 for Serverless and this is how we define allowed http methods in our .yml file.

```
provider:
    name: aws
    region: us-west-1
    apiGateway:
    binaryMediaTypes:
        - '*/*'
    httpApi:
        cors: true
        allowedMethods:
            - GET
            - POST
            - PUT
            - DELETE
            - PATCH
    functions:
        ...
```